# Export to CSV without opening

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, sharepoint

I am using an Excel Macro that detects two worksheets and writes them to CSV format in their current SharePoint directory. However, upon executing the macro, it proceeds to open the newly created files within the same workbook and gives me the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Sorry, we couldn't find C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application...
>
> Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Can I perform the "Save As" without opening the new file and avoiding the given error?

To be clear, it performs the core function just fine, as the new CSV files are properly written to the Sharepoint folder, I simply want to avoid the error message.

Macro code is as below:

```
Sub Export()
'
' Export Macro
' Export Rules and Privileges to 'Rules.csv' and  Privileges.csv'
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String

path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Rules" Then
        ws.Activate
        ws.SaveAs Filename:=path & "Rules.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    End If
    If ws.Name Like "Privileges" Then
        ws.Activate
        ws.SaveAs Filename:=path & "Privileges.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    End If
Next
    Range("B9").Select
    Application.Run "RulesWorkbook.xlsm!Export"
    Range("B4").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't this have spaces in it? `ProgramFiles(x86)` -> `Program Files (x86)` ?

Comment: A) Unless you're just double checking that it's hit the correct worksheet, there's no need for `ws.Activate` - `ws` already refers to the sheet you want to save, so `ws.SaveAs` will be saving the correct one. B) `Application.Run "RulesWorkbook.xlsm!Export"` is going to run your `Export` macro a second time. I'm guessing that this macro lives in "RulesWorkbook.xlsm", so the error message you're getting is the only thing preventing an infinite loop/stack overflow error. This looks quite unintentionally recursive.

Comment: @braX, Yes, there should be a space there. I hand-typed the error message as highlighting wasn't available.

Comment: @FreeMan That does solve the error messages! I am working on stopping it from opening the newly generated CSV files.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to FreeMan for the solution in getting rid of the error message. While I did not figure out how to prevent Excel from opening the newly generated programs, I was able to side-step that by closing the workbook upon macro execution. Updated code for the macro is below:

```
Sub Export()
'
' Export Macro
' Export SecurityRules and Privileges to 'Rules.csv' and 'Privileges.csv'
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String

path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Rules" Then
    ws.SaveAs Filename:=path & "Rules.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
End If
If ws.Name Like "Privileges" Then
    ws.SaveAs Filename:=path & "Privileges.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
End If
Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following just before the Save As line helped for me, not sure why

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.  Please consider formatting code with `styling` for a better visually appealing answer.